# How to lock the contents of a cell based on the contents of some other cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to lock a particular range of cells say "A1:A2"  based on the content of cell "B1". If the content of cell "B1" is anything other than "_" then the range "A1:A2" should get locked. Till now I have been using this code but it doesn't seem working.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Sheet1.Range("B1") <> "_" Then
Sheet1.Range("A1:A2").Locked = True

End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me fix this

**One more doubt:**
Since I am using "SelectionChange" event so it will be activated as soon as I select any other cell in the sheet. Does it make the sheet work slower or hang because I have a lot of other macros and buttons working in the sheet

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Worksheet_Change` event instead, and only proceed if the contents of `B1` are changed

This line

```
Range("A1:A2").Locked = ([b1].Value <> "_")
```

locks `A1:A2` if `B1` doesn't equal `_`, unlocks if it does.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, [b1])
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Range("A1:A2").Locked = ([b1].Value <> "_")
End Sub
```

Comment: I added `Range("A1:A2").Locked = ([b1].Value <> "_")` in a button, and changed the values in cell "B1" and checked it by pressing button again and again but nothing is happening, it's not showing any kind of error but its not working

Comment: This code needs to go into the sheet code (right click the sheet tab, *View Code*) - not a button

Comment: I copied your whole code in the sheet 1                                             
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, [b1])
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Range("A1:A2").Locked = ([b1].Value <> "_")
End Sub`
But it is still not working, may be I am doing some mistake and I am unable to  locate it, the problem is its not even throwing any error

Comment: Are you changing cell B1 to trigger it?

Comment: Yes, I am changing cell B1 to trigger it